# File path with cmake add_definitions

Tags: cmake, preprocessor, addition, definition

I am trying to replace a hard coded preprocessor

```
#define MY_FILE_PATH "/usr/local/myfile"
```

with add_definitions in cmake

```
add_definitions(-DMY_FILE_PATH=${MY_FILE_PATH})
```

and while calling cmake I use `-DMY_FILE_PATH=/usr/tmp/myfile`
but get all kind of errors e.g., expected primary expression before '/' token and tmp not find etc.
Is it possible to use add_definitions in my scenario or should I try configure_file.
Does add_definitions only supports integer values?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with quotes?

Comment: Yes, that was first thing I tried but same error. Although if I echo with double quotes it displays it correctly. I am using zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code defined the macro to a string literal, but your CMake code is defining it to a sequence of tokens. In ohter words, you dropped the quotation marks.

Add them back when invoking CMake:

```
-DMY_FILE_PATH="/usr/tmp/myfile"
```

(You might have to escape them properly for your shell).

Comment: The command which worked so far on my zsh $'"/usr/tmp/myfile"'

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `add_definitions`; it is deprecated as of CMake 3.12. Use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) instead. This code works as far back as CMake 3.0.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(example)

set(MY_FILE_PATH "/usr/local/myfile")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE "MY_FILE_PATH=\"${MY_FILE_PATH}\"")
```

If main.cpp contains:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main () { std::puts(MY_FILE_PATH); }
```

Then we get the following interaction:

```console
dev@host:~/example$ cmake -S . -B build
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dev/example/build
dev@host:~/example$ cmake --build build/
...
[100%] Built target main
dev@host:~/example$ ./build/main
/usr/local/myfile
```

---

Though it is always preferred to use target properties, if you *must absolutely* use a directory property, the function replacing `add_definitions` is [`add_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html). You could call it like so:

```cmake
add_compile_definitions("MY_FILE_PATH=\"${MY_FILE_PATH}\"")
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. You can simplify by removing some quotes like this though :
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE MY_FILE_PATH="${MY_FILE_PATH}")

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers here and from googling the internet worked for me (CMake 3.4.1 on Windows). I've finally found a solution, so here you go, hope this helps someone:

The trick is to quote the whole content of each definition you want to add with `add_definitions`, not just the value part of it, and escape the inner quotes which will go to the shell. Remember that each definition should consist a separate string. Like this:

```
add_definitions( "-D_SOME_DEFINE=\"Some value with spaces, etc\"" "-D DEF1=\"Another string\"")
```

The answer isn't restrained to paths only, but is applicable to any general string you want to supply as a preprocessor directive. It is the only way I was able to supply a string containing space characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_definitions(-DMY_FILE_PATH=\\"${MY_FILE_PATH}\\")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

In case someone faces the same problem, I found the proper solution, quotation marks required here
add_definitions(-DMY_FILE_PATH=$"{MY_FILE_PATH}")
This solves the issue.
After that just
-DMY_FILE_PATH="/usr/tmp/myfile"
works fine.

Answer (score -2):

On Windows this worked for me:

```
set(INT_TESTDATA_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testdata)
add_definitions(-DTESTDATA_DIR=R\"\(${INT_TESTDATA_DIR}\)\")
```

TESTDATA_DIR is then defined as:

```
#define TESTDATA_DIR R"(C:/aaa/bbbb/ccc/testdata)"
```