# cmake warnings about line break with backslash

Tags: cmake

I want to have a nice clean 80 column CMakeLists.txt. I tried to use line break in one of the lines but then I got a warning about it (3rd line below):

```
else()
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="%{time dd:MM:yyyy-h:mm:ss:zzz} %{type} \
        %{pid}\t%{message}"
    )
endif()
```

And here is the warning:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:78:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 28

  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
```

How can I fix this? or do it properly?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947974/file-path-with-cmake-add-definitions) answer help?

Comment: @vre Unfortunately I can not see how that thread can help me. Didn't see my problem tere.

Comment: The issue is with the quoting. See full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the quoting not with the line break. The error message points at line 78, column 28 (there's a quote next to this position). You need to enclose the entire argument in quotes and escape the inner quotes , so your `target_compile_definitions` argument would become:

```
"QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN=\"%{time dd:MM:yyyy-h:mm:ss:zzz} %{type} \
         %{pid}\t%{message}\""
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947974/file-path-with-cmake-add-definitions) for further explanations.

A small CMake test project looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(quoteTest)
add_executable(quoteTest main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    "QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN=\"%{time dd:MM:yyyy-h:mm:ss:zzz} %{type} \
    %{pid}\t%{message}\""
)
```

Comment: Ok this works fine. The only issue was that the tab character did not need to be escaped!

Comment: Thanks, I did not explore how this compile definition would need to be formulated. Anyway, I'll edit the answer.